# Link button no longer launching to colorbox

Tags: php, jquery, colorbox

I just had to update to a newer version of colorbox due to deprecated jQuery.

Previously I had a colorbox linked to the submit button on a form (presenting"thanks for your message!")

Since updating colorbox, this no longer works.

This was the original code that worked with colorbox 1.3, not on colorbox 1.4

```
  function SendMailForm(){
    var dataString = $("#form1").serialize();
    $.ajax({
      type:"POST",
      url:"sendmail.php",
      data:dataString,
      cache:false,
      success:function(html){
       $("#HiddenBox").show();
       $("#HiddenBox").html(html);
       $.fn.colorbox({'href':'#HiddenBox', 'open':true, 'inline':true, 'width':'600px', 'height':'200px'});
       $(document).bind('cbox_closed', function(){
        $("#HiddenBox").hide();
      });

     }  
   });
  }
```

Hitting the submit button caused `#HiddenBox` to show using `.show()`

Hidden box code is pretty simple colorbox code:

```
<div id="HiddenBox" style='display:none'>
      <span class="colorBox">Thanks for your message</span>
        <p>I'll get back to your query as soon as I can!</p>
    </div
```

Can't actually find any JS errors on the page relating to this, but it no longer launches the colorbox!

See real site [here](http://www.jamesperrett.co.uk/) and try to fill in the form

The form:

```
<form id="form1" class="formular" method="post" action="Javascript:SendMailForm();">
    <fieldset>
      <input  data-validation-placeholder="Name" class="validate[required] text-input" type="text" name="reqplaceholder" id="reqplaceholder" placeholder="Name" data-prompt-position="topRight:-79,15" />
    <br /><br />
      <input  data-validation-placeholder="Email" class="validate[required] text-input" type="text" name="reqplaceholder" id="reqplaceholder" placeholder="Email" data-prompt-position="topRight:-79,15" />
    <br /><br />
      <textarea value="What's on your mind?" data-validation-placeholder="Message" class="validate[required] text-input message" type="text" name="message" id="reqplaceholder" class="message" placeholder="What's on your mind?" data-prompt-position="topRight:-79,15" ></textarea>
    <br /><br />
  <input class="button" type="submit">
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Sendmail:

```
<?php
  $name = $_POST['name'] ;
  $email = $_POST['email'] ;
  $message = $_POST['message'] ;

  if(mail( "blah@jamesperrett.co.uk", "Message via JamesPerrett.com",
    $message, "From: $email" )):
      echo "<div id='contact_thanks' style='padding:10px; background:#fff;height:200px;'>";
      echo "<span class='colorBox'>Thanks!</span>";
      echo "<p>Thanks for your message, I'll get back to you as soon as I can!</p>";
      echo "</div>";
  endif;
?>
```

Comment: You still have js error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'" try to fix it first

Comment: Inspecting with Firebug and I get: Error: `Permission denied to access property 'toString'`  Enjoy

Comment: @roasted peculiar.. just fixed that and no longer seeing the error. Has fixed other problems but this remains... `.live` no longer used so should work?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether the colorbox that we are talking about are the same, I used this:

http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/

As I can see, it support ajax directly(`$('.ajax').colorbox()`), so I don't understand why you write the code yourself, but it doesn't matter.

However, seems you want the html respond with ajax shown in the color box, and after user close the colorbox, it show hidden content originally in the document. And the following code do that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="colorbox.css" />
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="jquery.colorbox.js"></script>

        <script language='javascript'>
            function SendMailForm() {
                var dataString=$('#form1').serialize();

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'sendmail.php',
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success:
                        function (html) {
                            $('#HiddenBox').show();
                            var node=document.createElement('div');
                            node.innerHTML=html;
                            document.body.appendChild(node);
                            id_1.click();
                            document.body.removeChild(node);
                        }
                });
            }

            $(document).ready(
                function () {
                    $('.inline').colorbox({ inline: true, width: '50%' });
                }
                );
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form id='form1' class='formular' method='post' action='javascript:SendMailForm();'>
            <fieldset>
                <input data-validation-placeholder='Name' class='validate[required] text-input' type='text' name='reqplaceholder' id='reqplaceholder' placeholder='Name' data-prompt-position='topRight:-79,15' />
                <br /><br />
                <input data-validation-placeholder='Email' class='validate[required] text-input' type='text' name='reqplaceholder' id='reqplaceholder' placeholder='Email' data-prompt-position='topRight:-79,15' />
                <br /><br />
                <textarea value="What's on your mind?" data-validation-placeholder='Message' class='validate[required] text-input message' type='text' name='message' id='reqplaceholder' class='message' placeholder="What's on your mind?" data-prompt-position='topRight:-79,15' ></textarea>
                <br /><br />
                <input class='button' type='submit'>
            </fieldset>
        </form> 

        <a id='id_1' class='inline' href="#contact_thanks" style='display: none'></a>

        <div id='HiddenBox' style='display:none'>
            <span class='colorBox'>Thanks for your message</span>
            <p>I'll get back to your query as soon as I can!</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Note the `a` tag of `id_1` links to the same document `contact_thanks` which is responded by `sendmail.php`, I added a node for the responding html and remove after the colorbox is shown.